# Ignore group in regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to extract a number which is followed by certain text for example:

```
CR33318
ALM33318
QC33318
CR 33318
ALM 33318
QC 33318

CR33318 123567
ALM33318 123567
QC33318 123567
CR 33318 123567
ALM 33318 123567
QC 33318 123567
```

From the above example I only want `33318` to be extracted. The length of the number is not fixed. What is the regular expression for this?

Comment: It depends on what language you are using. And what you have tried.

Comment: @stribizhev Not only has he tried, but he also succeeded. He answered his own question ~30 seconds later.

Comment: @w0lf Actually i was posting this question but then StackOverflow did not allow me to post because it was giving error that i had to wait 90 minutes to post. This question was my first question for the day. Hence i was trying later i got the solution for myself. Hence i thought the same could be useful to others. Hence shared the question and answer after 90 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?:ALM|CR|QC)[ ]*([0-9]+)` is the solution for this